# Assembly not found in mono asp.net web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, web-services, mono

Im trying to do develop a simple web service in asp.net using Mono with Apache. The problem is that i need to use a private Dll, but i can't reference it right so i get a "Assembly 'Custom.PrivateClass' not found" exception

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Debug="True" Class="Custom.TestingWebService" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Custom.PrivateClass" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using Custom.PrivateClass;

namespace Custom.TestingWebService
{

    [WebService]
    public class TestingWebService: System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public String Test()
        {
            return PrivateClass.TestMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried other options like

```
<%@ Assembly Name="PrivateClass.dll" %>
```

But with the same result. I don't know if it's a mono, asp.net, or apache problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. In the app directory i had to create a "bin" directory. Inside that folder i put all my Dlls, and from the .asmx y called the Dll by its Assembly name, as i set before compile in my Visual Studio project

```
<%@ Assembly Name="PrivateClass" %>
```